# How to store intermediate recursion results

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I would like to get the same result which is printed (using the print function in the code below) as function result. If I use a return statement in the loop, then the loop get's broken and I never get to the indexes > 0. 
How can I store the intermediate result in a (local) variable and eventually return as function result?

```
l = list("ABCD")

def remel(l, pos):
    res = l[:]
    del res[pos]
    return(res)

def f(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        res = l
        return(res)
    else:
        for i in range(len(l)):
            res = [l[i]] + f(remel(l, i))
            print(res) # store this and pass on how?
        return(res)

f(l)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) for accessing intermediate recursion results. From an example given in that discussion, say you're computing a *sum* of first `n` numbers:

```
function tailrecsum(x, running_total = 0) {
    if (x === 0) {
        return running_total;
    } else {
        return tailrecsum(x - 1, running_total + x);
    }
}
```

here, the `running_total` is being passed to each of the calls so you can have access to the intermediate recursion calls by accessing this variable:

```
tailrecsum(5, 0)
tailrecsum(4, 5)
tailrecsum(3, 9)
tailrecsum(2, 12)
tailrecsum(1, 14)
tailrecsum(0, 15)
# Returns 15
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` keyword immediately stops the execution of a function and jumps back to continue execution from where the function was called.
That being said, if you just want to store the values of `res` it can be done by replacing the last two lines of the function with the following code -

```
list_where_you_want_to_store.append(res) # Declare the list first, then keep appending res.
    return(list_where_you_want_to_store)
```

Then going forward, you can use the values stored in list where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved it:

```
l = list("ABCD")

def remel(l, pos):
    res = l[:]
    del res[pos]
    return(res)

def f(l, mem = [], minlen = 1):
    if len(l) == minlen:
        res = l
        if res not in mem: # no duplicates
            mem.append(res)
        return(res, mem)
    else:
        for i in range(len(l)):
            res_next = f(remel(l, i), mem)
            res = [l[i]] + res_next[0]
            res.sort() # sort
            if not mem: 
                mem = [res]
            elif res not in mem: # no duplicates
                mem.append(res)
        return(res, mem)

print(f(l)[1])

#['D']
#['C', 'D']
#['C']
#['B', 'C', 'D']
#['B', 'D']
#['B']
#['B', 'C']
#['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
#['A', 'C', 'D']
#['A', 'D']
#['A']
#['A', 'C']
#['A', 'B', 'D']
#['A', 'B']
#['A', 'B', 'C']
```